# Bootstrap tour popup-modal do not contain any content

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tour

When the tour is started, it gives me a blank popup modal, but the contents and title are present when I check with title, but bootstrap-tour is unable to load it.

```
    var tour;
        function initTour() {
            tour = new Tour({
               name: "tour",
               steps: [{
                   element: "#tab1",
                   title: "dashboardTitle",
                   placement: "right",
                   content: "dashboardContent"
               }],
        // container: "body",
        smartPlacement: true,
        keyboard: true,
        storage: window.localStorage,
        debug: false,
        backdrop: true,
        backdropContainer: 'body',
        backdropPadding: 0,
        redirect: true,
        orphan: true,
        duration: false,
        delay: false,
        debug: true,
        basePath: "",
        template: endTour,
        afterGetState: function(key, value) {},
        afterSetState: function(key, value) {},
        afterRemoveState: function(key, value) {},
        onStart: function(tour) {},
        onEnd: function(tour) {},
        onShow: function(tour) {},
        onShown: function(tour) {},
        onHide: function(tour) {},
        onHidden: function(tour) {},
        onNext: function(tour) {},
        onPrev: function(tour) {},
        onPause: function(tour, duration) {},
        onResume: function(tour, duration) {},
        onRedirectError: function(tour) {}
    });
    tour.init();
    tour.setCurrentStep(0);
    tour.start(true);
}

function startTour() {
    initTour();
}

// tour.init();
tour.start(true);
tour.goTo(step);
}
```

the dashboardTitle and dashboardContent are strings that needs to be displayed.

Comment: can you show more from your code

Comment: or add some working fiddle or snippet

Comment: edit your question with the code

Comment: Updated the code. Please check. template: endTour holds the HTML template for end. I am using bootstrap 4.